# What is the story of Kalighat Temple in Kolkata,West Bengal?

Tags: shiva, durga, parvati, kali, shakti

In Kolkata which is the capital of West Bengal,there is a big temple named ''Kalighat'' which is a temple of Goddess Kali and in this temple there is also a Shakti Peetha. What is the story of this temple?

Comment: http://www.westbengaltourism.gov.in/web/guest/kalighat This website gives story of Temple. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @Anil Kumar,thank you for your website! It gives me the full description of Kalighat Temple which is in Kolkata the capital of West Bengal state.